# postgres use SIMILAR TO for multiple words

Tags: sql, postgresql

I know SIMILAR TO keyword can be used as follows:

```
SELECT * from table WHERE column SIMILAR TO '(AAA|BBB|CCC)%';
```

Here the query fetches all columns which contains either AAA, BBB or CCC. From my understanding it works as `AAA OR BBB OR CCC`. If that is correct, then how can I implement a case where I need `AAA AND BBB AND CCC`. I went through the documentation and it doesn't specifically say on how to do this. I need to get all columns where it similar to all the given strings.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Write three conditions, joined by `AND`.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe SIMILAR TO 'AAA' AND SIMILAR TO 'BBB' AND SIMILAR TO 'CCC%'. Is that what you mean?

Comment: It should be `WHERE col SIMILAR TO 'AAA' AND col SIMILAR TO 'BBB' AND col SIMILAR TO 'CCC'`.

Comment: Although in that case you should use `column LIKE 'AAA%' AND column LIKE 'BBB%'` etc, as that's faster than regex.

Comment: @eurotrash I can't see that ever returning a value without leading wildcards too

Comment: @Scoots That's true. Nonetheless, it's exactly what the OP requested, based on his initial pattern (simply ANDing rather than ORing). But as you say, it will never return anything, so should should have leading wildcards as well (or OP needs to rethink what he's trying to do if he only wants columns that start with those values).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not talking about performance, but I think syntax is close - just need to add wildcard to each of alternations:

```
db=# with p(s) as (values('aaaxx'),('bbbxxx'),('cccxxx'),('dddxxx'))
select s, s similar to '(aa%|bb%)' from p;
   s    | ?column?
--------+----------
 aaaxx  | t
 bbbxxx | t
 cccxxx | f
 dddxxx | f
(4 rows)
```

https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-matching.html#FUNCTIONS-SIMILARTO-REGEXP